# Constant Loss with Multilayer Perceptron (Python)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I have created a single layer perceptron with data representation of the OR function (and bias) predicting a binary label. 
When I attempted to extend the problem to multiple layers (MLP), I am missing something; the predictions the model is outputting are incorrect.

I have adjusted my learning rate between 0.0001 → 1, the MLP's loss does not change.
However, the SLP is sensitive to changes in learning rate as I would expect.

```
def layer1(w,x,y,lr=.05):

    pred = np.asarray([i if i>=0 else 0 for i in np.dot(x,w)])

    error =  (pred-y)
    scaled_error = 2 * np.dot(x.T,error)

    w -= np.asarray(lr*scaled_error)
    return [w,pred,y]

def layer2(i,lr=.05):

    w = i[0]
    x = i[1]
    y = i[2]
    w2 = np.random.rand(len(x[0]),)

    pred = np.dot(x,w2)
    error =  (pred-y)

    scaled_error = 2 * np.dot(x.T,error)
    w2 -= np.asarray(lr*scaled_error)

    return w2

weights = layer2(layer1(w,x,y))
#binarize labels
pred = np.asarray([1 if i>=0 else 0 for i in np.dot(x,w])
#mse loss
loss = .5 * np.sum(pred-y)**2
```

My predicted values are all ones (e.g. [1, 1, 1, 1]) and therefore my loss graph is a constant line at 8.

Because my SLP worked on the same problem, I believe this problem is related to my implementation of the multiple layers. I specifically believe this problem lies in the way I calculate the gradient to update my weights ("scaled_error").

Comment: I don’t see backpropagation in the code.

Comment: @dyukha Am I incorrectly backpropagating when I use error → scaled error to change weights?

Comment: Oh, so you try to backpropagate simulationsly with forward propagation. It won’t work (comparing with y on layer 1 doesn’t make sense). I suggest you to read how to implement  backpropagation.